# How to use state variables without sharing among different components inside a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two cards component inside a loop as given below in the code. In the card I have a text field and an ADD button. Upon clicking on ADD button,the entered value in the text field will be populating inside the card. But when I do this , the other card is also showing the same value. That means , suppose I entered a value in the text field of the first card then the same value is showing in the second card as well. I know this is happening because I am using the same state variable inside the loop and which is sharing among the other card components inside the loop. I am not able to find a solution so that if I enter something in the text field of a card component then it will not reflect on other components inside a loop.

Here is the code: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-taussig-kgbot)

## Code , where I am rendering card components inside a loop

```
render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    let apidata = this.state.apidata;

    return (
      <div>

        <br />
        <br />
        <div className={classes.root}>
        <GridList cellHeight={600} cols={2} className={classes.gridList}> 
            {apidata.map((val,index) => (                             
              <GridListTile className="gridtile" key={val.id}>
                <Card className={classes.card} key={val.id} >
                  <CardHeader

                    title={val.username}                    
                  />

                    <Typography className={classes.test}>
                     <span>{this.state.img_comments}</span>
                    </Typography>

                    <TextField
                      label="Add a comment"
                      className={classes.textField}
                      margin="normal"
                      onChange={(e)=>this.commentHandler(e,index)}
                      defaultValue=""
                    />

                    <Button
                      variant="contained"
                      color="primary"
                      className={classes.button}
                      onClick={this.putComment}
                    >
                      ADD
                    </Button>

                </Card>
              </GridListTile>

            ))}
            </GridList>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. You need to change your state which storing the comment to object.

```
this.state = {
  date: "",
  apidata: [],
  favColor: 0,
  commentFlag: 0,
  count: 0,
  id: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  comments: [],
  img_comments: {},
  hdn_img_comments: []
};
```

Changes in your putComment function

```
putComment = (key) => {
// e.preventDefault();
let obj = this.state.img_comments;
obj[key] = this.state.hdn_img_comments;

this.setState({ img_comments: obj });

 };
```

And Some minor change in your add button

```
<Button
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
    className={classes.button}
    onClick={() => this.putComment(val.id)}
    >
     ADD
</Button>
```

Here is the link to code:  [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-pike-27lzw)